# Передача массива байтов через асинхронный итератор websockets python

Tags: python, byte, websokets

Я пишу сервер на питоне, который будет общаться с планшетом посредством вебсокетов. Все было хорошо, пока не дошёл до логики отправки изображений. Пользуюсь асинхронным модулем websockets, и, как я понял, метод send может работать с асинхронным итератором. Но натыкаюсь на одну и ту же странную проблему. Для теста написал простой сервер и клиент и пытаюсь отправить изображение из одной папки в другую, но какой бы размер буффера я не задал, всегда через какое-то кол-во итераций клиент отваливается со следующей ошибкой:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 827, in transfer_data
    message = await self.read_message()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 950, in read_message
    frame = await self.read_data_frame(max_size=max_size)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 971, in read_data_frame
    frame = await self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 1051, in read_frame
    extensions=self.extensions,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\framing.py", line 127, in read
    f"payload length exceeds size limit ({length} > {max_size} bytes)"
websockets.exceptions.PayloadTooBig: payload length exceeds size limit (65561 > 65536 bytes)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test2.py", line 27, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(client())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 583, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File ".\test2.py", line 15, in client
    async for message in websocket:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 439, in __aiter__
    yield await self.recv()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 509, in recv
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 812, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason
```

Вот код сервера:

```
async def send_photo(id: int, camera: str):
                async with aiofiles.open("photos/photos_camera_" + camera + "/" + str(id) +".jpg", 'rb') as f:
                    size = os.path.getsize(os.getcwd() + "\\photos\\photos_camera_"+ camera + "\\" + str(id) + ".jpg")
                    print(size)
                    sent = 0
                    chunk = await f.read(2 ** 16)
                    while chunk:
                        yield chunk
                        #print('sent ' + str(len(chunk)))
                        chunk = await f.read(2 ** 16)
                        sent += len(chunk)
                        print(str(sent) + '/' + str(size))

async def hello(websocket:websockets.WebSocketClientProtocol, path):

    id = 1
    camera = 'rear'
    
    await websocket.send(send_photo(id, camera))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8080)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Вот код клиента

```
async def client():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8080"
    websocket = websockets.connect(uri)
    
    

    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        i = 1
        async for message in websocket:
            print(len(message))
        
        #async with websocket.recv() as f:
        #    print(len(f))
        #with open(f"photos/photos_camera_top/{i}.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        #    while True:
        #        chunc = await message.read(1024)
        #        if not chunc: break
        #        f.write(chunc)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(client())
```

Comment: Ограничение 65кб на картинку? Странно, ведь у сервера по умолчанию ограничение в 2**20 : https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.server.serve Кст, добавьте полный стек с ошибкой (и посмотрите в коде библиотеки откуда `max_size`, нужно уметь работать с чужим кодом :) )

Comment: Я пробовал разный размер буффера. Итог один - в какой-то момент клиент говорит, что он не укладывается в ограничение по памяти. Так же я менял значения max_size, но всё бестолку. Возможно, у меня страдает какая-то логика?

Comment: Не знаю в чем проблема... Посмотрите тут или задайте вопрос автору библиотеки: https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues?q=PayloadTooBig